# How to link two databases together?

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 databases that are supposed to be linked by a foreign key: DealershipListing and Dealers.

Here are their models:

```
class Dealer(models.Model):
    dealersName = models.TextField(('DealersName'))
    zipcode = models.CharField(("zipcodex"), max_length = 15)
    zipcode_2 = models.CharField(("zipCode"), max_length = 15)  
    state = models.CharField(("state"), max_length=5)
    address = models.TextField(("Address"))
    ids = models.BigIntegerField(("ids"), primary_key=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dealersName

class DealershipListing(models.Model):
    uniqueID = models.IntegerField(("CarID"), primary_key=True)
    vincode = models.CharField(('vinCode'), max_length=255)
    price = models.CharField(('price'), max_length=30)
    msrp = models.CharField(('msrp'), max_length=30)
    mileage = models.CharField(('mileage'), max_length=9)
    is_new = models.BooleanField(('isNew'))
    first_seen = models.CharField(("first_seen"), max_length=15)
    last_seen = models.CharField(("last_seen"), max_length=15)
    model = models.CharField(("Models"), max_length= 255)
    make = models.CharField(("Make"), max_length=255)
    year = models.CharField(("Year"), max_length= 4)
    ids = models.ForeignKey(Dealer, on_delete=CASCADE)
    color = models.CharField(("ExtColor"), max_length=255, null=True, blank = True)
    intcolor = models.CharField(("IntColor"), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.year + " " + self.make + " " + self.model
```

But when I go check the admin database, the DealershipListing is a dropdown of the names of every dealership in the Dealer model, but the ids on the DealershipListing model is placed in the place of color. What am I doing wrong? How do I connect each car in the DealershipListing to their Dealership by the ids?

Comment: I don't know how you are getting the dropdown on DealershipListing as you don't have any Foreign Key for the model. Also your id is placed on the color field is pretty weird can you post a image of your DealershipListing admin page.

Comment: @sumit subedi https://imgur.com/rQkPguh

Comment: and in that dropdown I have the name of all the dealerships from the Dealer. There is a foreign key for that model, it is "ids = models.ForeignKey(Dealer, on_delete =CASCADE"

Comment: Sorry, normally Foreign keys are placed at the top of the model(would also recommend you to do so) so I didn't check thoroughly. Your model is fine you now have to set the dealer from the dropdown and those delaer and listing would be connected to each other. As to why that field is null don't make any sense. I think the on_delete must be models.CASCADE as I always do so and havenot tried your way yet. I think this answers your question also check with models.CASCADE and reply if you have any more questions.

Comment: I tried models.CASCADE and it is still the same. By set the dealer from the dropdown do you mean i have to select each one of them manually? because my table has 122393 rows and that would not be possible

Comment: You can also set it programmatically. You might have some constraint right as to this listing will be of this delaership then you can do as :

`listings = DealershipListing.objects.all()`
`for item in listings:
 #use condition as to what dealership should be for the listing`
`    #eg dealer = Dealership.objects.get(id = item.id)`
`   item.ids = dealer`
`    item.save()`

Comment: just a last question, that should be done in the views.py right?

Comment: Yeah you can do it but, I would recommend doing it in shell. You can access django shell by `python manage.py shell` command.

Comment: Ok so I found another issue. the id field is going to the color field, the color field is going to the intcolor view and apparently the intcolor view is going to the id field. I got an error when i tried printing {{car.ids}} that said "Field 'ids' expected a number but got 'Charcoal Black'.". Do you know what this might be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239728/discussion-between-sumit-subedi-and-gabriel-trezza).